# Autolayout updates view after it's been displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I'm having some issues with using `AutoLayout` for some pretty simple images and text. 
After the view has been displayed to the user, the image (and text) is resized and relocated on the screen. This gives the impression of the app being "laggy".

The (vertical) setup is quite simple:

```
-------------------------------HEADER-------------------------------
---Text1-----------------------Text2------------------------Text3---
---[                                                            ]---
---[                                                            ]---
---[                           IMAGE                            ]---
---[                                                            ]---
---[                                                            ]---
```

Have anyone experienced something similar using `AutoLayout`, and know how I can fix it? Or if you haven't, what would be the best way to correctly set up this (using `StoryBoards`) so it works across the different screen sizes?

Comment: Are the images and text loaded before the view is displayed? Or are you doing some asynchronous loading?

I've had similar issues when setting text/images in the viewDidAppear method, but not with static text/images.

Comment: @MikeWelsh Everything is set in `storyboard`, no code used for these simple static view-controllers. 

However, what I do notice is that the image is actually displayed on the screen, then minimized (just slightly) and moved down at the same time.

Comment: will you please share your code

Comment: @Jageen there is no code. I'm **only** using Storyboards for these static `ViewControllers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found that it was resolved by changing the constraints NOT to take into account the margins. It seems as though (sometimes?) the margins are calculated after the view is displayed which causes the jump. I have not had a problem with this generally, but it was certainly the problem in this instance.

[image]